# Cannot access getElementsByTagName from external js

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

This thing is driving me mad... I have a simple js script wich checks for all the links tag () in a page and check if two of those links at least correspond to a given href attribute.
If I put the script in the main page as an inline script it works great. If I put it inside an external .js script on the same page, it doesn't find any  element. Just like if it's only scanning its internal ones but not the parent document ones.
the script is this

```
            var as,i,islink,l1,l2;
        l1 = false
        l2 = false
        as=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(i=0;i<as.length;i++)
        {
            islink=as[i].href;
alert(islink);

            if(islink == 'http://www.linktocheck.com/')
            {
                if(!as[i].getAttribute('rel')) {l1 = true;}
            }
            if(islink == 'http://www.linktocheck.com/somedir/somepage.asp')
            {
                if(!as[i].getAttribute('rel')) {l2 = true;}
            }
        }
        if(!l1 || !l2) {alert('links not found in the page');}
```

I put alert(islink); for debug purposes to see if some link element has been found in the page or not.
The HTML of the calling page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1"><title>page a</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type" /></head>
<body>
<script src="externaljstochecklinks.js?PARAMETER=somevalue" id="uniqueid" type="text/javascript"></script><div style="margin-top: 6px;margin-bottom: 4px;text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.linktocheck.com/somedir/somepage.asp" title="" target="_blank">[...]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.linktocheck.com/" title="" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.linktocheck.com/skins/some/images/some.gif" alt="" style="border: none;vertical-align: middle;" /></a></div>
```

Why if I put the link check script inline it finds the  elements if I put it as external it doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for the DOM to finish loading before you can query it to find DOM elements.

Your script appears to be at the beginning of the `<body>` section which means it will execute BEFORE the DOM has been parsed and loaded.  Thus, there is nothing yet loaded to find.

The simplest fix would be to move your `<script>` tag to the end of the body right before the `</body>` tag.  You could also use an event listener and execute your code only when the event fires indicating that the DOM is ready.

Comment: I thought this the first time as well but the function was wrapped with the onload event.
I tryed again now with an attach event method this time window.addEventListener('load', function() { } )
but it doesn't work if I copy the whole thing (with attach event) in the html it works if I copy in an external js it doesnt... it's paranormal! I can send you the 2 small files (html and js) and you see it's crazy

Comment: @Manight - we can't help you when you don't disclose the relevant code.  `document.getElementsByTagName()` works just fine from an external JS file is the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thank you mate! I was about to posting the complete code (didn't want to bug you with full listings that's all) when I hade an idea!
Since in the external JS there are document.write lines as well, wrapped in an onload event themselves, I tryed to move the onload event of the link checking code BEFORE the onload event of the document writes and it worked. It's still a bit counter intuitive to me but i works. What really was misleading for me is that I tryed with a blank external script with just the link check code and it didn't work, but maybe I guess it was some cache related issue :(

Comment: @Manight - If `document.write` is used AFTER the document has loaded, it clears the document and starts writing a new document.

Comment: You are right I'm really dumb... I moved the doc write out of the other onload attached event.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the url to the external.js file is correct, the problem might be with the synchronous loading of the js files.

As soon as the js file is downloaded, it starts running. If this happens before the DOM finished loading, it can't find any `<a>` tag because they don't exist yet.

To test the hypothesis, include your external js file at the end of the `<BODY>` tag and see if it works.

To fix this issue permanently (and you don't want to include a JS file at the end of the body, you can defer the loading by either:

1. using an external library (such as jquery) and place the code inside `$(document).ready()`
2. placing your code inside `window.onload` event
3. trigger your own "ready" event